# Multiple plots in R on one page using par(pin) result in wasted space

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot several plots in r, 24 to be exactly in one page. Furthermore, I want the plots to have a rectangular form. However when I use:

```
par(mfrow = c(6,4),pin = c(2,1))
```

I get a plot with massive white space wasted, at the bottom and top of the plots. If I try to reduce the outer margin of the plots using:

```
par(mfrow = c(6,4),pin = c(2,1), oma = c(0,0,0,0))
```

the result is the same.

Comment: There's unwanted space around **each** figure, or around the group of 24?

Comment: There is no space between one plot and the next one , but there is massive white space on the page at the top and at the bottom of each plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can control for margins, I have you already tried this:

```
    layout(matrix(c(1:24), nrow = 6, byrow = T));par(mfrow = c(6,4),pin = c(2,1), oma = c(0,0,0,0));
for (i in 1:24) { plot(rnorm(100), main = sprintf("%do gráfico", i)) }
```

[image]

Comment: Now using that I don't get the free space... but my plots don't look rectangular anymore. And even though I change the pin vector I keep getting the same result.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting what you want. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, it's getting better. However when I open the pdf device first and start to plot using a loop and then closing the device. I get the same white space as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set "margin options" and "pin" at once, but can "plt". First par() sets lower y (or x), upper x, and y. Second par() calculates lower x (or y) from "fin" and the aspect ratio, and sets it.

```
# sets lower y and calculates lower x
par( plt = c( 0, 0.97, 0.22, 0.97) )
par( mfrow=c(6,4), mgp = c(3, 0.5, 0), 
     plt = c( par("plt")[2] - par("pin")[2] * 2 / 1 / par("fin")[1], par("plt")[2:4]) ) 
for (i in 1:24) plot(rnorm(100), ann=F)

# sets lower x and calculates lower y
par( plt = c( 0.2, 0.97, 0, 0.97) )
par( mfrow=c(6,4), mgp = c(3, 0.5, 0), 
     plt = c(par("plt")[1:2], par("plt")[4] - par("pin")[1] * 1 / 2 / par("fin")[2], par("plt")[4]) )
for (i in 1:24) plot(rnorm(100), ann=F)
```